# count line changes with git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Is there a simple way I can ask git for the amount of lines I added (or add and removed) in a specific date range?

I'm using git on Windows, Linux and TortoiseGit(Windows)

Comment: Something both posters seem to have missed is that there's a `--numstat` option, which gives a much more machine-readable format than `--stat`.

Comment: @Jefromi: What makes you think I missed it? ' 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)' is no harder to parse in `awk` than '2       0       .gitconfig' and saves me tallying the number of files changed!

Comment: Also check out [@quorian's great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9933440/24874) which gives counts of lines added, removed and modified.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Building upon [Seth Robertson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240808/count-line-changes-with-git/6240832#6240832), (+1 Seth!) `awk` will tally up the columns for you:

```
% git log --stat --author $(git config --get user.email) --since="last year" --until="last month" | awk -F',' '/files? changed/ {
    files += $1
    insertions += $2
    deletions += $3
    print
}
END {
    print "Files Changed: " files
    print "Insertions: " insertions
    print "Deletions: " deletions
    print "Lines changed: " insertions + deletions

}'
```

Comment: This seems useful, but how do I invoke this in Terminal? Not familiar with `awk`.

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée: In [tag:Bash] or [tag:Zsh], you can just past my answer straight in (without the leading `% `. Or you could put this into a script somewhere in your `${PATH}`.

Comment: This can yield incorrect results! The summary line of `stat` may hide `deletions` or `insertions` if there are none. If there are no insertions in that particular commit, then git may show `1 file changed, 6 deletions(-)`, making your script add the deletions to `insertions` variable.

Comment: one could modify the awk script to use matching
`match($0, /([0-9]+) files? changed(, ([0-9]+) insertions?\(\+\))?(, ([0-9]+) deletions?\(\-\))?/, m); files += m[1]; insertions += m[3]; deletions += m[5];`

Comment: Thanks @thrau. The git output has changed a little in the five years since I wrote this post.

Comment: your answer was definitely correct at the time! the comments in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13056003/804840 indicate that the output changed during a 1.7.9 -> 1.7.10 patch.

Comment: @Johnsyweb are you sure about the no of lines changed obtain through `insertions-deletions`, as not only the lines that are caused by modification, the line which deleted are also in the count of deletions. so how do we identify them exactly

Answer (score 9):

```
git log --stat --author me --since="last year" --until="last month"
```

You can then post-process the --stat information at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is interested in an overall statistics of the repo:

1. Right click on the repo folder, select **TortoiseGit/Show Log**.
2. Click **Statistics** at the bottom of the dialog.  [image: Statistics]