# Is there a way of having git show lines added, lines changed and lines removed?

Tags: git, git-diff

`git diff --stat` and `git log --stat` show output like:

```bash
$ git diff -C --stat HEAD c9af3e6136e8aec1f79368c2a6164e56bf7a7e07
app/controllers/application_controller.rb |   34 +++-------------------------
1 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 30 deletions(-)
```

But what really happened in that commit was that 4 lines were changed and 26 lines were deleted which is different than adding 4 lines and deleting 30.

Is there any way of getting the delta LOCs (26 in this case)? I don't really care about differentiating between lines added or removed.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

For per-file numerical diff information:

```bash
git diff --numstat
```

For aggregated numerical diff information:

```bash
git diff --shortstat
```

As far as separating modification from an add and remove pair, `--word-diff` might help. You could try something like this:

```
MOD_PATTERN='^.+(\[-|\{\+).*$' \
ADD_PATTERN='^\{\+.*\+\}$' \
REM_PATTERN='^\[-.*-\]$' \
git diff --word-diff --unified=0 | sed -nr \
    -e "s/$MOD_PATTERN/modified/p" \
    -e "s/$ADD_PATTERN/added/p" \
    -e "s/$REM_PATTERN/removed/p" \
    | sort | uniq -c
```

It's a little long-winded so you may want to parse it in your own script instead.

Comment: Thanks quornian but numstat gives exactly the same info as stat, additions and deletions.

Comment: Updated my answer to include an example use of `--word-diff`. That might be more useful.

Comment: Thanks! Your edited answer is great. I wanted to see how many lines were added/modified/removed between two specific commits. To others who may wish to do the same, just put the branch names in the command, as in: `git diff commit1 commit2 --word-diff ...` where commit1/2 are SHA1s, branches, tags, etc...

Comment: The output of `git diff --numstat` is broken down by file. To see the total added/removed for the diff, you can pipe it to awk: `git diff --numstat | awk '{ added += $1; removed += $2 } END { print "+" added " -" removed }'`

Comment: @hughes A simpler way of obtaining the same information would be `git diff --shortstat`. In my experience it is equivalent to accumulating the output of `git diff --numstat`.

Comment: Also FWIW to see the stats for staged changes, simply add `--cached`

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering about the output from `--numstat`, the two numbers are lines added and lines removed in that order, so `1       10      test/some_test.rb` means 1 added and 10 removed.

Answer (score 117):

1. If you want to know the lines added/changed/deleted by a commit with
   id `commit-id`, you could use

   ```
   git show commit-id --stat
   ```

   or

   ```
   git diff commit-id-before commit-id --stat
   ```
2. If you wat to know the lines added/changed/deleted by a range
   commits, you could use

   ```
   git diff commit-id1 commit-id2 --stat
   ```
3. If you want to know the lines added/changed/deleted by each commit,
   you could use

   ```
   git log --stat
   ```

Comment: That solution doesn't answer the question, "git --stat" counts a single modified line as "1 insertion and 1 deletion". The question asks how to get "1 changed".

Answer (score 30):

You could use [`diffstat`](https://invisible-island.net/diffstat/manpage/diffstat.html) to show the number of modified lines. For example:

```sh
git diff HEAD c9af3e6136e8 | diffstat -Cm
```

The `-C` option is for getting colorized output; the `-m` option is for showing the number of modified lines. Sample output:

```
 app/controllers/application_controller.rb |   30 -------------------!!!
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-), 4 modifications(!)
```

Note that the number of lines in each category (insertions, deletions, modifications) is only approximate, as `man diffstat` says:

> **-m**  merge insert/delete counts from each "chunk" of the patch file to approximate a count of the modified lines.

`diffstat` has a missing feature when compared to `git diff --stat`: `diffstat` is incapable of showing file moves/renames (e.g. `app/{a.rb => b.rb}`), unlike `git diff --stat` which is capable of showing this information by using the `-M` (`--find-renames`) option or by setting `diff.renames` in the git configuration file (refer to `man git-config`).

Comment: This needs more upvotes as it actually shows _modifications_! Thanks

Answer (score 17):

If all of your files are staged for commit, to see the `--numstat` go like this:

```
git diff --numstat --cached
```

example output

```
32      32      project.pbxproj
```

> `--numstat` [...] shows number of added and deleted lines

Answer (score 5):

git uses "unified" diff, which only has added and deleted lines, as the diff format.  You have to do something external to get a diff that shows add, delete, and change information.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Git#Context_diffs_with_Git gives links to a script that allows running regular old "diff" - and from that you can generate a ["context" diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Context_format) output.  Context diff does show added, removed, and changed lines, which should allow you to get the data you want.

Comment: Voted down for linking to an article instead of reproducing the relevant information here. The article no longer contains the relevant section. (Admittedly, it happens to be a wiki with available edit history, but Stack Overflow answers should stand on their own regardless.)

Comment: For anyone who wants to easily get to the content that was removed in an edit, here a link to the old page:  https://wiki.postgresql.org/index.php?title=Working_with_Git&oldid=31690#Context_diffs_with_Git