# Can you get the number of lines of code from a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, line-count

In a GitHub repository you can see “language statistics”, which displays the *percentage* of the project that’s written in a language. It doesn’t, however, display how many lines of code the project consists of. Often, I want to quickly get an impression of the scale and complexity of a project, and the count of lines of code can give a good first impression. 500 lines of code implies a relatively simple project, 100,000 lines of code implies a very large/complicated project.

So, is it possible to get the lines of code written in the various languages from a GitHub repository, preferably without cloning it?

---

The question “[Count number of lines in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4822471/388916)” asks how to count the lines of code in a local Git repository, but:

1. You have to clone the project, which could be massive. Cloning a project like Wine, for example, takes ages.
2. You would count lines in files that wouldn’t necessarily be code, like i13n files.
3. If you count *just* (for example) Ruby files, you’d potentially miss massive amount of code in other languages, like JavaScript. You’d have to know beforehand which languages the project uses. You’d also have to repeat the count for every language the project uses.

All in all, this is potentially far too time-intensive for “quickly checking the scale of a project”.

Comment: Do you want the lines in all revisions or just the latest revision?

Comment: @Schwern: Didn't really think about that. The latest commit of the master branch, I suppose.

Comment: @Abizern: Is that a valid reason for closing a question? I'm trying to find that [in the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). My plan was to ask on SO first. If that proved futile, I'd ask Github customer support and post their information as an answer here.

Comment: @Abizern: See [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It says you can ask questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: @Hubro 1 I've solved with `git clone --depth 1`.  As for 2 and 3, I suspect there is software out there which can do the analysis for you, and you can do a lot of guessing based on file extensions, but I'm having a hell of a time coming up with a good search term to find said software.  Maybe you need to ask another question.

Comment: @Hubro Ah ha!  https://github.com/github/linguist

Comment: My apologies however there are far more answers than the accepted one on that page :)

Comment: There's an online tool at https://codetabs.com/count-loc/count-loc-online.html, haven't tried if it's any good.

Comment: count-loc is good, but limited to repos of <500mb. It errors out on my own company's open source database repo. :/

Comment: The fact is, github doesn't provide any apis through which you can get the loc of your github files. What else you can do is, if you can Sonar server integrated with your github, Sonar does provide apis to get LOC of your files

Comment: In Windows this command works as well: 
`(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Get-Content | Measure-Object -Line).Lines`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### Not currently possible on Github.com or their API-s

I have talked to customer support and confirmed that this can not be done on github.com. They have passed the suggestion along to the Github team though, so hopefully it will be possible in the future. If so, I'll be sure to edit this answer.

Meanwhile, [Rory O'Kane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012789/388916) is a brilliant alternative based on `cloc` and a shallow repo clone.

Comment: Not directly, but their [Statistics API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/) has all the data you need to calculate it yourself. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32154303/2220891) below for a quick script that does this.

Answer (score 709):

> You can run something like

```
git ls-files | xargs wc -l
```

Which will give you the total count!

[image: lines of code]

You can also add more instructions. Like just looking at the JavaScript files.

```
git ls-files | grep '\.js' | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: The short answer to the question (finding this number using github) is No. Your approach is the second best alternative, specially since we can filter out whatever files we need to count out.

Comment: If you want to filter, e.g., Python code: `git ls-files | grep '\.py' | xargs wc -l`.

Comment: I was doing `xargs` to `wc -l` all files manually then use `awk` to sum the column, OMG this is so much easier.

Comment: This simple approach includes comments in files. Comments and blank lines are not always considered "lines of code".

Comment: Well, documentation is a huge part of code. Where would you draw the line really if you kick out comments. What about comments that contain code info like params, what about comments that disable ESLint for the next line — what about lines which are 80% comments after some code. See where I am going with this.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm not a bash expert, but I've had luck using `sed` with this to ignore blank lines and comments (in this example, ruby comments, which are prepended by `#`). `git ls-files | xargs sed "/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d" | wc -l`

Comment: http://line-count.herokuapp.com/ seems to not recognize a large number of languages, including Haskell.

Comment: This method includes assets like pictures and documents. How do we specify multiple file extensions?

Comment: @AhmadAwais An irrelevant question : How did you create the terminal interface graphics ? green and purple background for commands is very beatiful

Comment: This method does not work. `xargs wc -l` does not pass the entire file list to a single `wc` invocation - for a large repository, it will split the list of files into smaller lists (to avoid exceeding maximum command length restrictions), and the last "total" will only be the total of the last `wc`. If you scroll up you'll see other "total" lines. From `man xargs`: "-n number Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for each invocation of utility...The current default value for number is 5000." So if you have more than 5000 files, the result will be incorrect.

Comment: if you want the total you have to `grep total` and sum them because xargs can issue the command more than once

Comment: git ls-files --exclude-standard -- ':!:**/*.[pjs][npv]g' ':!:**/*.ai' ':!:.idea' ':!:**/*.eslintrc' ':!:package-lock.json' | xargs wc -l

to exclude common file types that should ~probably~ be ignored

from Neonexus here -> https://gist.github.com/mandiwise/dc53cb9da00856d7cdbb

Comment: I do agree with @LoganPickup, but still 1 vote for this approach, rather than having to install a new package just to count the lines. To avoid the last line "total", we could use "| tail -n+1", to get rid of > 5000 files I think we still could solve it by command line

Comment: Definitely the short answer is the best.

Comment: @sam no worries, it's my theme called Shades of Purple you can install any version of it from https://ShadesOfPurple.pro/more (what you see above is iTerm2 and Zsh themes).

Comment: What terminal is that and may I know the colour theme and zsh theme?

Comment: Note: link doesn't work as of recent

Comment: Only js files inside of ```src``` folder ```git ls-files | grep 'src' | grep '\.js' | xargs wc -l```

Comment: Searching for multiple extensions: `git ls-files | egrep '\.go|\.ts' | xargs wc -l`.

Comment: I ended up using `git ls-files | xargs -I {} find "{}" -type f -exec wc -l {} \;` because I have a lot of file names with spaces in them and the original command `git ls-files | xargs wc -l` chokes on spaces in file names.

Comment: Search only interested file types: `git ls-files | egrep -i '\.(vue|ts|js)$' | xargs wc -l`

Comment: powershell: 

$totalLines = 0
$lineCounts = git ls-files | Where-Object { $_ -match '\.java$' } | ForEach-Object {
    $filePath = $_
    if (Test-Path $filePath) {
        $lineCount = (Get-Content $filePath).Count
        $totalLines += $lineCount
        [PSCustomObject]@{Lines=$lineCount; File=$filePath}
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find file at path $filePath"
    }
}

$lineCounts | Format-Table -AutoSize
Write-Host "Total Lines: $totalLines"

Comment: `bc <<< $(git ls-files | grep '\.go$'  | xargs wc -l | grep total | sed 's/total//g' | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/\+$//g')`

Comment: For window users the command "git ls-files | xargs wc -l" won't work so try this one:
This will give you the numbers of lines of each file:
`git ls-files | foreach { Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -Line | Select Lines }`

This will give you the sum of it:
`git ls-files | foreach { Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -Line | Select -ExpandProperty Lines } | Measure-Object -Sum | Select -ExpandProperty Sum`

Answer (score 458):

## A shell script, `cloc-git`

You can use this shell script to count the number of lines in a remote Git repository with one command:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git clone --depth 1 "$1" temp-linecount-repo &&
  printf "('temp-linecount-repo' will be deleted automatically)\n\n\n" &&
  cloc temp-linecount-repo &&
  rm -rf temp-linecount-repo
```

### Installation

This script requires [CLOC](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) (“Count Lines of Code”) to be installed. `cloc` can probably be installed with your package manager – for example, `brew install cloc` with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). There is also [a docker image published under `mribeiro/cloc`](https://hub.docker.com/r/mribeiro/cloc/).

You can install the script by saving its code to a file `cloc-git`, running `chmod +x cloc-git`, and then moving the file to a folder in your `$PATH` such as `/usr/local/bin`.

### Usage

The script takes one argument, which is any URL that `git clone` will accept. Examples are `https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i.git` (HTTPS) or `git@github.com:evalEmpire/perl5i.git` (SSH). You can get this URL from any GitHub project page by clicking “Clone or download”.

Example output:

```
$ cloc-git https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i.git
Cloning into 'temp-linecount-repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 200, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (182/182), done.
remote: Total 200 (delta 13), reused 158 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (200/200), 296.52 KiB | 110.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
('temp-linecount-repo' will be deleted automatically)


     171 text files.
     166 unique files.                                          
      17 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.62  T=1.13 s (134.1 files/s, 9764.6 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Perl                           149           2795           1425           6382
JSON                             1              0              0            270
YAML                             2              0              0            198
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           152           2795           1425           6850
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Alternatives

### Run the commands manually

If you don’t want to bother saving and installing the shell script, you can run the commands manually. An example:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i.git
$ cloc perl5i
$ rm -rf perl5i
```

### Linguist

If you want the results to match GitHub’s language percentages exactly, you can try installing [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) instead of [CLOC](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc). According to [its README](https://github.com/github/linguist#usage), you need to `gem install linguist` and then run `linguist`. I couldn’t get it to work ([issue #2223](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2223)).

Comment: The original question specified without cloning the repo.

Comment: @linuxdan My script doesn’t clone the whole repo; it passes `--depth 1` to only download the most recent commit. For most repos, this avoids the original question’s concern about cloning taking too long.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane can we use `cloc` to get the lines of code in a github repository with out cloning the repo to our machine ( through online ). the above given `cloc-git` aslo first clones to project before starts counting the no of lines

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Sorry, I don’t know of any online website that runs `cloc` for you. In order for `cloc` to count lines in code, your computer has to download that code, though only temporarily. Note that even web browsers are technically downloading web pages when you visit them; they just save them to memory instead of to disk.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane yeah that fine, but there will be a problem when the repo is too big. Any way is there is a way to get the output of the `cloc` to a array or some variable in `bash`

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Since the answer to that question could be complicated, you should ask that in a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Standalone questions can have comments of their own and multi-line answers.

Comment: How to apply this answer if I want # lines from particular time in history and not from the latest commit?

Comment: @user13107 Follow the “Run the commands manually” section, but increase the `--depth` limit or remove it altogether so that the commit from history will be downloaded, not just the latest commit. Then before running `cloc`, run `git checkout b25fb1`, where `b25fb1` is the SHA, branch name, or tag name of the commit in history you want to count the lines of.

Comment: This seems to be the most useful answer. However, I think that the alternative solution with manually running the commands should be at the top as it is the most straight-forward one.

Comment: Might seem obvious, but if you have the code on your local computer already, there is no need to clone again and you can just run cloc on the repo.

Answer (score 222):

I created an extension for **Google Chrome browser** - [GLOC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gloc-github-counter-lines/kaodcnpebhdbpaeeemkiobcokcnegdki) which works for public and private repos.

Counts the number of lines of code of a project from:

- project detail page
- user's repositories
- organization page
- search results page
- trending page
- explore page

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: upvoted although it doesn't seem to work for private repositories

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Thank you for your suggestion. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks! also for https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter I was getting negative number of lines yesterday

Comment: It's a horrible case. I'll check it soon. Thank you for help @MichailMichailidis

Comment: @ArtemSolovev just tried your plugin - it's pretty good :) Not a huge fan of the gradient but the functionality is there.. so thanks!

Comment: @tech4242 actually i love the gradient since it makes it easier to understand that the page is being modified by an extension.

Comment: @Taurus my comment was not meant as a CR - from a usability standpoint the gradient does the job (for the reason you mentioned) I meant that I am not a fan of the chosen colors but that's just my (subjective) opinion. Cheers :)

Comment: @tech4242 One question, What does "CR" mean ? I searched it up but "Carriage Return" and "Copyright" did not make sense, i am digesting it as  "Criticism".  
My humble opinion, but again, i believe that the outlandish colors do a great job of expressing what i mentioned, however, i do agree that another choice of color would look more appealing and probably express the point just as well.

Comment: doesn't work for repos in private organizations that I am a member of, any chance to fix that?

Comment: @hellyale sure. in a few weeks

Comment: @hellyale It works for private repos too. Update extension. There is more new features to use

Comment: @Taurus  design was changed today

Comment: @Artem_Solovev Love it!

Comment: I guess this just count lines, not lines of code. Compared to SonarQubes counting of loc, this is factor 2-3 bigger...

Comment: It would be nice to show number of lines in each repo in the repo list

Comment: Look at the second screen @IgorCova

Comment: @ArtemSolovev this work only after refresh (F5), if you just move from Overview to Repositories - then the number of rows for each repo is not shown

Comment: @IgorCova I know it. To add this functionality I need to sacrifice 10KB for one line

Comment: @IgorCova If you know more optimal method welcome to PR

Comment: @IgorCova Now it works how you proposed) 13KB not so big deal so i moved back jQuery

Comment: @ArtemSolovev, do you have any plan on adding support for counting SLOC instead of LOC? thanks

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan Hi man. By the end of the Sept. it will be released. You can subscrube to this issue https://github.com/artem-solovev/gloc/issues/104

Comment: wow, feels great to see such a prompt reply from the creator, thanks again

Comment: might want to add a disclaimer that you're the author (pretty sure it's required by SO)

Comment: @somebody thank you, just mentioned that. Have a good day )

Answer (score 100):

If you go to the graphs/contributors page, you can see a list of all the contributors to the repo and how many lines they've added and removed.

Unless I'm missing something, subtracting the aggregate number of lines deleted from the aggregate number of lines added among all contributors should yield the total number of lines of code in the repo. (EDIT: it turns out I was missing something after all. Take a look at [orbitbot's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository/32154303#comment63416385_32154303) for details.)

UPDATE:

This data is also available in GitHub's [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/). So I wrote a quick script to fetch the data and do the calculation:

```js
'use strict';

async function countGithub(repo) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/stats/contributors`)
    const contributors = await response.json();
    const lineCounts = contributors.map(contributor => (
        contributor.weeks.reduce((lineCount, week) => lineCount + week.a - week.d, 0)
    ));
    const lines = lineCounts.reduce((lineTotal, lineCount) => lineTotal + lineCount);
    window.alert(lines);
}

countGithub('jquery/jquery'); // or count anything you like
```

Just paste it in a Chrome DevTools snippet, change the repo and click run.

Disclaimer (thanks to [lovasoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository#comment57206195_32154303)):

Take the results of this method with a grain of salt, because for some repos (sorich87/bootstrap-tour) it results in negative values, which might indicate there's something wrong with the data returned from GitHub's API.

UPDATE:

Looks like this method to calculate total line numbers isn't entirely reliable. Take a look at [orbitbot's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository/32154303#comment63416385_32154303) for details.

Comment: Right. But in some cases where the project is a large open-source community project, this sort of count isn't feasible.

Comment: @franklin Definitely. However, this data is also available in GitHub's [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/), so you can write a script to calculate the total number of lines pretty easily. I updated my answer with a quick script that I just wrote up.

Comment: It would be more simple to use the code_frequecy API. Giving:


```fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/stats/code_frequency").then(x=>x.json()).then(x=>alert(x.reduce((total,changes)=>total+changes[1]+changes[2],0)))```

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting: test your code on sorich87/bootstrap-tour . The result is negative.

Comment: @lovasoa You're right, it looks like there's something wrong with the data the API is returning for that repo. I did a quick approximation manually using the data on the [contributors page](https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/graphs/contributors) and the result does look like it'll end up being negative (31349 - 18169 + 72669 - 87594 + 26774 - 27695 + 1211 - 428 = -1883). I tried your version with code_frequency and it also seems to return a negative value, but a different one. =/

Comment: The data in the add/remove section does as noted not add up to the total lines of code in the repository at a specific time, it is an aggregate of lines added or removed per user over the whole commit history. The data content is not faulty, it's just different to what you assumed it would be.

Comment: @orbitbot I might be missing something, but shouldn't the aggregate of all lines added by each user subtracted by the aggregate of all lines deleted by each user over the entire commit history be equal to the current number of lines in the repo? I also really can't think of a scenario where that number can be negative (a repo with more lines deleted than added over its lifetime??).

Comment: @Lewis I think you're disregarding that lines added/removed in one commit can be the same as other commits, f.e. when merging branches etc. which still count towards the same total. Additionally, f.e. the Github contributions stats for user profiles are only counted from the default branch or gh-pages, so there might be something similar going on for the commit/line stats: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/ . Also note that the user profile stats only count the previous year, but I think that the commit stats on the graph page are permanent.

Comment: @orbitbot Thanks, the results make a lot more sense now. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 50):

You can clone just the latest commit using `git clone --depth 1 <url>` and then perform your own analysis using [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist), the same software Github uses.  That's the only way I know you're going to get *lines* of code.

Another option is to [use the API to list the languages the project uses](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-languages).  It doesn't give them in lines but in bytes.  For example...

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/evalEmpire/perl5i/languages
{
  "Perl": 274835
}
```

Though take that with a grain of salt, that project [includes YAML and JSON which the web site acknowledges](https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i/search?l=yaml) but the API does not.

Finally, you can use [code search](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code) to ask which files match a given language.  This example asks which files in perl5i are Perl.  `https://api.github.com/search/code?q=language:perl+repo:evalEmpire/perl5i`.  It will not give you lines, and you have to ask for the file size separately using the returned `url` for each file.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that. Can you confirm that it can't be done on the Github website, though?

Comment: I can't confirm it, but I don't see anything in the API or on the Github web site that will give you lines.  It's all bytes or percentages.  What's your rationale for doing it through the API instead of cloning?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info though. I'll ask Github support.

Comment: Linguist looks cool, but how do you get it to show you *lines* of code though? It looks like it shows bytes by default, just like the API.

Comment: @Hubro Dunno, you might have to patch it.

Comment: According to the [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) tool, the evalEmpire/perl5i repository currently has 6382 lines of Perl, compared to 272319 bytes reported by the GitHub API call you give. That’s 43 bytes per line. So perhaps a good rule of thumb is to divide the API’s returned numbers by 40 to get lines of code.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Since everyone's coding style is different, some's lines are longer, while others' are shorter. It's not very accurate to do that.

Comment: This method is wrong now. I tested and found it give a much big value.

Answer (score 40):

From the @Tgr's comment, there is an online tool :
 https://codetabs.com/count-loc/count-loc-online.html

[image: LOC counting example for strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator repository]

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work for big repositories like Git.

Answer (score 25):

You can use [tokei](https://github.com/XAMPPRocky/tokei):

```
cargo install tokei
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/XAMPPRocky/tokei
tokei tokei/
```

Output:

```
===============================================================================
 Language            Files        Lines         Code     Comments       Blanks
===============================================================================
 BASH                    4           48           30           10            8
 JSON                    1         1430         1430            0            0
 Shell                   1           49           38            1           10
 TOML                    2           78           65            4            9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Markdown                4         1410            0         1121          289
 |- JSON                 1           41           41            0            0
 |- Rust                 1           47           38            5            4
 |- Shell                1           19           16            0            3
 (Total)                           1517           95         1126          296
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Rust                   19         3750         3123          119          508
 |- Markdown            12          358            5          302           51
 (Total)                           4108         3128          421          559
===============================================================================
 Total                  31         6765         4686         1255          824
===============================================================================
```

---

Tokei has support for badges:

#### Count Lines

```
[![](https://tokei.rs/b1/github/XAMPPRocky/tokei)](https://github.com/XAMPPRocky/tokei)
```

[image]

> By default the badge will show the repo's LoC(Lines of Code), you can also specify for it to show a different category, by using the ?category= query string. It can be either code, blanks, files, lines, comments.

#### Count Files

```
[![](https://tokei.rs/b1/github/XAMPPRocky/tokei?category=files)](https://github.com/XAMPPRocky/tokei)
```

[image]

Comment: or once tokei is istalled u can simply navigate to the folder directory and find it out too.

Example:-

$ tokei ./src 

         /*this would give you the number of lines in the src folder*/

Answer (score 17):

Hey all this is ridiculously easy...

1. Create a new branch from your first commit
2. When you want to find out your stats, create a new PR from main
3. The PR will show you the number of changed lines - as you're doing a PR from the first commit all your code will be counted as new lines

And the added benefit is that if you don't approve the PR and just leave it in place, the stats (No of commits, files changed and total lines of code) will simply keep up-to-date as you merge changes into main. :) Enjoy.

[image]

Comment: but what if the first commit contains 10000lines,  then this number doesn't show that 10000lines right?

Comment: If you can afford to ignore first commit then this is a great quick way to check. +1

Comment: If you do this backwards and open a PR deleting all your code, then the number of lines deleted will be the total lines in the project (minus ignored files). Just do yourself a favor and don't merge it.

Answer (score 14):

You can use GitHub API to get the sloc like the following function

```
function getSloc(repo, tries) {

    //repo is the repo's path
    if (!repo) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("No repo provided"));
    }

    //GitHub's API may return an empty object the first time it is accessed
    //We can try several times then stop
    if (tries === 0) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Too many tries"));
    }

    let url = "https://api.github.com/repos" + repo + "/stats/code_frequency";

    return fetch(url)
        .then(x => x.json())
        .then(x => x.reduce((total, changes) => total + changes[1] + changes[2], 0))
        .catch(err => getSloc(repo, tries - 1));
}
```

Personally I made an chrome extension which shows the number of SLOC on both github project list and project detail page. You can also set your personal access token to access private repositories and bypass the api rate limit.

You can download from here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-sloc/fkjjjamhihnjmihibcmdnianbcbccpnn

Source code is available here https://github.com/martianyi/github-sloc

Comment: For the chrome extension how is SLOC determined? All file types? Exclude specific directories?

Comment: @BrettReinhard It's based on [the number of additions and deletions per week](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-number-of-additions-and-deletions-per-week), I think it includes all files.

Comment: Doesn't that just return the number of changes in the last week?

Comment: @Johannes'fish'Ziemke No, it returns every week

Answer (score 13):

Open terminal and run the following:

```
curl -L "https://api.codetabs.com/v1/loc?github=username/reponame"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for private repos.

Comment: Does not work any longer. API responds with "Moved Permanently" for any repo.

Comment: @Magne it's still working for me. Mind you repo has to be public. You can try their UI(https://codetabs.com/count-loc/count-loc-online.html) to be sure

Answer (score 12):

## Firefox add-on *Github SLOC*

I wrote a small firefox addon that prints the number of lines of code on github project pages: [Github SLOC](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-sloc/)

Comment: Great plugin, very helpful! Do you know if it's possible to make it work with private repos? It seems to be only showing LOC on public repos.

Comment: The link is dead and after searching manually, it seems, that sadly this plugin doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: There's a request up for making GLOC available for Firefox too, and the developer seems open to the idea: https://github.com/artem-solovev/gloc/issues/23

Comment: @miyalys It's done now: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gloc/

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install sloc -g
```

```bsh
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/vuejs/vue/
sloc ".\vue\src" --format cli-table
rm -rf ".\vue\"
```

#### Instructions and Explanation

1. **Install [sloc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sloc) from npm**, a command line tool ([Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) needs to be installed).

```
npm install sloc -g
```

2. **Clone shallow repository** (faster download than full clone).

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/facebook/react/
```

3. **Run sloc** and specifiy the path that should be analyzed.

```
sloc ".\react\src" --format cli-table
```

sloc supports formatting the output as a `cli-table`, as `json` or `csv`. Regular expressions can be used to exclude files and folders ([Further information on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sloc#usage)).

4. Delete repository folder (optional)

Powershell: `rm -r -force ".\react\"` or on Mac/Unix: `rm -rf ".\react\"`

Screenshots of the executed steps (cli-table):

[image: sloc output as acli-table]

sloc output (no arguments):

[image: sloc output without arguments]

It is also possible to get details for every file with the `--details` option:

```
sloc ".\react\src" --format cli-table --details
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for R files like .R or .Rmd

Comment: @jzadra It should work. R is documented as a supported language https://www.npmjs.com/package/sloc#supported-languages

Otherwise create an issue on github https://github.com/flosse/sloc/issues

Comment: You might also want to to try out SCC: https://github.com/boyter/scc

Answer (score 10):

You could use [ghloc.vercel.app](https://ghloc.vercel.app) - it allows to count lines in any public Github repository.
[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Easy to use with quick LOC count. Bonus that it also provides info on existence of common repo items (aka "health")

Answer (score 8):

If the question is "can you *quickly* get NUMBER OF LINES of a github repo", the answer is no as stated by the other answers.

However, if the question is "can you *quickly* check the SCALE of a project", I usually gauge a project by looking at its size. Of course the size will include deltas from all active commits, but it is a good metric as the order of magnitude is quite close.

E.g.

How big is the "docker" project?

In your browser, enter api.github.com/repos/ORG_NAME/PROJECT_NAME
i.e. api.github.com/repos/docker/docker

In the response hash, you can find the size attribute:

```
{
    ...
    size: 161432,
    ...
}
```

This should give you an idea of the relative scale of the project. The number seems to be in KB, but when I checked it on my computer it's actually smaller, even though the order of magnitude is consistent. (161432KB = 161MB, du -s -h docker = 65MB)

Answer (score 7):

Pipe the output from the number of lines in each file to `sort` to organize files by line count.
`git ls-files | xargs wc -l |sort -n`

Comment: Even gives me a total at the bottom, this is by far the easiest and fastest way.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of answers here, some overly complicated. Here is a simple approach for 2023:

```
git ls-files > list.txt && cloc --list-file=list.txt
```

A text file called `list.txt` includes the filenames in your git repo, then cloc runs on the file list, respecting the gitignore.

You will need to to install [cloc](https://cloc.sourceforge.net/).

Note that this method requires the cloned repo on your system - not exactly what the original poster was asking for.

[image: cloc]

Comment: The premise of the original answer was *without cloning the repository*, i.e. without having it available locally. You've entirely skipped that part in your answer, assuming that the repository is already available locally.

Comment: Yup, I made a note about this.

Answer (score 6):

This is so easy if you are using **Vscode** and you clone the project first. Just install the `Lines of Code (LOC)` Vscode extension and then run `LineCount: Count Workspace Files` from the Command Pallete.

The extension shows summary statistics by file type and it also outputs result files with detailed information by each folder.

Answer (score 3):

There in another online tool that counts lines of code for public and private repos without having to clone/download them - https://klock.herokuapp.com/

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looked promising but very strange that you have to sign up for it.

Comment: I think it is because it doesn't want to exceed the API request limit from one account, so it asks everyone to login so it's counted towards their own account. But "This application will be able to read and write all public and private repository data." is not a proportional risk to ask people to take.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here satisfied my requirements.  I only wanted to use existing utilities.  The following script will use basic utilities:

- Git
- GNU or BSD awk
- GNU or BSD sed
- Bash

Get total lines added to a repository (subtracts lines deleted from lines added).

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --shortstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD | \
sed 's/[^0-9,]*//g' | \
awk -F, '!($2 > 0) {$2="0"};!($3 > 0) {$3="0"}; {print $2-$3}'
```

Get lines of code filtered by specified file types of known source code (e.g. `*.py` files or add more extensions, etc).

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --shortstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD -- *.{py,java,js} | \
sed 's/[^0-9,]*//g' | \
awk -F, '!($2 > 0) {$2="0"};!($3 > 0) {$3="0"}; {print $2-$3}'
```

`4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` is the id of the "empty tree" in Git and it's always available in every repository.

Sources:

- My own scripting
- [How to get Git diff of the first commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883798/how-to-get-git-diff-of-the-first-commit)
- [Is there a way of having git show lines added, lines changed and lines removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933325/is-there-a-way-of-having-git-show-lines-added-lines-changed-and-lines-removed)

Answer (score 2):

[shields.io](https://shields.io) has a badge that can count up all the lines for you [here](https://shields.io/category/size#:%7E:text=Lines%20of%20code,provider/%3Auser/%3Arepo). Here is an example of what it looks like counting the Raycast extensions repo:

[image: https://img.shields.io/tokei/lines/github/raycast/extensions]

Answer (score 1):

You can use sourcegraph, an open source search engine for code. It can connect to your GitHub account, index the content, and then on the admin section you would see the number of lines of code indexed. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I made an NPM package specifically for this usage, which allows you to call a CLI tool and providing the directory path and the folders/files to ignore

it goes like this:

`npm i -g @quasimodo147/countlines`

to get the `$ countlines` command in your terminal

then you can do
`countlines . node_modules build dist`