# Get number of lines of code modified from GitHub repository

Tags: python, git, github, github-api

I have a repository on GitHub from which I have to find some statistics, then I have to process this data in a Python script. In particular, the information I have to get is the number of lines of code modified in a certain amount of days, i. e. the number of lines of code added, deleted and modified.
I tried to take a look at the bees of GitHub but unfortunately I have not found what I need, would anyone know how to advise me what to do?
Thank you.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, and already a many answers with nearly identical question titles, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CLOC](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc)(“Count Lines of Code”), which will give you a breakdown of significant and insignificant lines of code by language.

```
cloc $(git ls-files)
```

This `git ls-files` is same as `xargs cloc`.

Or another way to get number of coded line is to use...

```
git ls-files | xargs wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command in your repository :

```
git log --format='%aN' | Sort-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_
    $addedLines = 0
    $removedLines = 0
    (git log --author="$name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat) | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '(\d+)\s+(\d+)') {
            $addedLines += [int]$matches[1]
            $removedLines += [int]$matches[2]
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Author = $name
        AddedLines = $addedLines
        RemovedLines = $removedLines
        TotalLines = $addedLines - $removedLines
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I hope this helps you.