# Count the number of lines from git default branch within ALL repositories without downloading

Tags: github, azure-devops, inline-code

Is it possible to count the number of lines of code from ALL repositories without downloading?

For example in the screenshot below, in Azure DevOps, all repositories under Repos->Branches,

1 Fabrikam and other repositories under Branches.

2 Only the default master branch in each repository, e.g. there are two branches, `main` and `main1`, only the default branch `main` is needed.

3 Without downloading any code

[image]

The question below asks if it is possible to count LOC from one repository without downloading.
[Can you get the number of lines of code from a GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository?rq=1)

The question below requires downloading code.
[Count number of lines in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822471/count-number-of-lines-in-a-git-repository)