# Number of files/lines of code from *github.Repository

Tags: github-api

Is there any way to get the total number of files & the total number of lines of code from *github.Repository.

There is a Go package that helps explore git in Go code. The Repository class in which we are speaking is [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v40@v40.0.0/github#Repository).

As per this documentation, looks like there is no direct way to get the total number of files or a total number of lines of code.

Any expert who can shed light on this or a workaround for this?

I got to know about 'total_count' field in the response schema but that is just the total count of the results returned. Not related to what we are speaking here.
Cloc is probably another option but it would create a dependency to maintain this.

Comment: This has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository

Comment: Another option would be to iterate the files via the API and count files and LOC in Go. Not sure how performant that is. Would need some parallelization, but beware of potential github API limits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022016/get-all-file-names-from-a-github-repo-through-the-github-api

Comment: Please note that you should only use a particular programming language tag if you have a _practical_ problem to solve _in_ that language. The fact you're using some ready-made package written in that language to perform some abstract task is not relevant to problems you might have achieving that abstract task. I mean, you could as well use a github web API wrapper written in Python, Ruby, Perl, FroBozz and so on. This question is about particularities of that web API, not programming in Go. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also consider searching [Github discussions](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/categories/api-and-webhooks) and start another one, if relevant.

Comment: @kostix, You are probably right that this question is not about the language itself. However, it is probably fair to tag 'go' since the code itself is in go language including the user code & the package code. Isn't it?

Comment: @TehSphinX, Thanks for the reference. However, I went through this already and this is not related to the rest api.

Comment: Yes, the answers are not related to the API, because it seems the github API doesn't provide the numbers out of the box. See my second comment above for an alternative using the github API.

Comment: [1/2] «However, it is probably fair to tag 'go' since the code itself is in go language including the user code & the package code. Isn't it?»–I beg to disagree. The rules of SO are [reasonably clear](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You'd mark your question `[go]` if you'd have problem with actually _using the language_ – like, say, you'd need to implement some complex logic to process an API response and would have troubles doing so (i.e. your code won't do you intended it to).

Comment: [2/2] Note that troubles with properly calling the public API of some ready-made Go package still may qualify as a proper question–especially given that some 3rd-party packages are underdocumented. But such questions are expected to have some display of the OP trying to solve their own problem–not mere "how do I…?"-style questions. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question about `go` language.

It's a shell question.

I would do in `zsh`:

```
$ git clone [your repo]
$ print -l **/*.go |wc -l # number of files
$ cat **/*.go | wc -l # number of lines
```

Comment: That seems what people revert to mostly. Still it means the repository first must be cloned locally. The question wants to know how to get the information via the github API.

Comment: @TehSphinX, Yes, You are right. The question is about getting the count through the github API's.