# After pushing commit to github, code changes showing wrong

Tags: git, github, sublimetext2, core.autocrlf, phpdesigner

**Problem :** Here is the real [Code Difference](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=5ro0d) & in my commit in github is showing `@@ -1,202 +1,251 @@` as this file has been replaced completely. I want to see the difference in code like the below image in github.

### [image]

**System Information :** I am editing my code in windows 8.1 with sublime text 2 & in windows 7 with phpdesigner 7

**Solutions, I tried before commit :**

- Changed the Line formatting settings in my editor to windows/unix/macOSx
- In my .gitattribute added `* text=auto`
- I have also tried `dos2unix` & `unix2dos` commands
- **Strangely, If I edit using vi, it works. But, I am not comfortable using that.**

**My .gitattribute :**

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto

# Custom for Visual Studio
*.cs     diff=csharp

# Standard to msysgit
*.doc    diff=astextplain
*.DOC    diff=astextplain
*.docx diff=astextplain
*.DOCX diff=astextplain
*.dot  diff=astextplain
*.DOT  diff=astextplain
*.pdf  diff=astextplain
*.PDF    diff=astextplain
*.rtf    diff=astextplain
*.RTF    diff=astextplain
```

Thanks.

Comment: I will delete my answer since it doesn't fit the problem you've specified in our conversation, perhaps this answer could [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933325/is-there-a-way-of-having-git-show-lines-added-lines-changed-and-lines-removed)

Comment: @e.doroskevic Thanks for looking into my problem. As I don't want other experts to misunderstand, may I request you to edit my question to resolve any fuzzyness?

Comment: @Arf that's a high praise. I appreciate that although I am far from it. I do not completely understand the problem, I may speculate and say you want something between the lines of what `git diff` does, but also including the line numbers. Perhaps, add a simple output example you'd want to see. This should help others to help you out

Comment: @e.doroskevic Thanks for your suggestion. I have added one image as per that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is **SOLVED**.

**What I did wrong**

- I run `unix2dos` not in recursive mode.
- I don't know why, but my .gitattribute file was one of the cause

**Solution**

- Run `find . -type f -exec unix2dos {} \;` This will automatically change all files to crlf/windows format
- Removed my .gitattributes file

And TADA, all working as it should be