# What are the changeset and codecurn in git

Tags: git, changeset

I want to ask about changeset and codecurn. How I get changeset and codecurn value from my git project?

I need this for development research data, I am successful to  get line of code, developer, diff time, etc by typing "git log --stat". But I am confused how to get changeset and codecurn value from my git project.

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to use these as metrics for some type of developer productivity. this effort will only result in failure and misery.

Comment: @Derek can you explain how this effort will only result in failure and misery? 
because this is my task in graduate program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "codecurn". I do know about "code churn", the total net change to the codebase which represents the amount of productive code effectively delivered.

See "[Why Code Churn Matterse](https://blog.gitprime.com/why-code-churn-matters/)" from **[Ben Thompson](https://twitter.com/thebent)**

[image: https://blog.gitprime.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/churn2.pnge]

You can query changesets with [`git log -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--p), and evaluate the churn with [git diff --numstat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933440/6309)