# Regular expression for --word-diff in git

Tags: regex, git

I am trying to update three regular expressions to identify patterns in git logs. Basically, they are expressions for identifying code line additions, modifications, and deletions from git annotations when running the `git diff ---word-diff --unified=0` command.

The expressions are:

**MODIFICATION**: `.+(\[-|\{\+).*$`

**ADD**: `\{\+.*\+\}$`

**REMOVE**: `\[-.*-\]$`

Originally, these expressions were presented in this question: [Is there a way of having git show lines added, lines changed and lines removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933325/is-there-a-way-of-having-git-show-lines-added-lines-changed-and-lines-removed?lq=1). But today, apparently, they are no longer working as they should, because when testing here, I found different numbers than they really should have

For the following code, it introduced different numbers of removals and modifications:

```
@@ -11 +11 @@ delta dAddressBook {
                        private String [-addressA;-]{+address;+}
@@ -13 +13 @@ delta dAddressBook {
                        public [-AddressBookEntryB()-]{+AddressBookEntry()+} {
@@ -39,0 +40,4 @@ delta dAddressBook {

                        {+public void setAddress(String address) {+}
{+                              this.address = address;+}
{+                      }+}
@@ -45,2 +48,0 @@ delta dAddressBook {
[-              import br.unb.cic.iris.core.exception.EmailException;-]
[-              import br.unb.cic.iris.core.model.AddressBookEntry;-]
```

On https://regex101.com/r/Soeey3/1/

For some reason, it is matching line 7 in this example (`{+public void setAddress(String address) {+}`), where this line should be accounted for addition and not modification. Similarly, the expression for addition does not match line 7.

Comment: Something is disconnected here. The target patterns changed, You're showing the old patterns with the new target, I can't gleen from your old regexes what it is supposed to match in the new target ...

Comment: @leomar-de-souza I'm thinking that your interpretation might be wrong here and not the regex. If you consider that line 7 includes white-space changes then it is a change and not an addition, depends on what is considered a change.

Comment: I just tested ADD with your example, and it's matching lines 2, 7, 8 and 9 for addition for me, whereas you said it didn't match 7 for you. I think you need to assess if you need `^` and `$` at the beginning or not, depending on whether you consider addition of a word inside a line an addition or a modification - the modification regex you should considers that a modification, in any case.