# How to show number of lines added and deleted for every file in git log and git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log, diffstat

If I do `git log <commit-id> --stat` or `git diff` with `--stat`, I get something like:

```
myproj/src/__main__.py                             |   1 +
myproj/{ => src}/utils.py                          |   0
myproj/{ => src}/web.py                            |  31 ++++-
3 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

The number next to each file is: `number_of_inserts + number_of_deletes`. This is not what I want. I want to know the number of lines added and deleted for each file (e.g. `+28 -3` instead of `31`).

- I know I could use `--numstat` instead of `--stat`, but `--numstat` will not produce the histogram.
- I also know that I  can use [`diffstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diffstat). For example, `git diff <commit-id> | diffstat -f4 -C`:

  ```
  myproj/src/__main__.py                             |   1    1    0 +
  myproj/src/web.py                                  |  31   28    3 ++++-
  2 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
  ```

  But here I lose information about file moves/renames (e.g. `myproj/{ => src}/web.py`).

So how can I get output similar to `--stat`, but with information about the number of lines added and the number of lines deleted for each file?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933325/is-there-a-way-of-having-git-show-lines-added-lines-changed-and-lines-removed).

Comment: @Jay-Pi No, that question is about showing the number of lines modified. This question is about showing the number of additions and deletions for each file. I know this because I actually answered the question  you linked to.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question carefully. How about `git log --numstat --stat`? The output seems redundant, but it includes the histogram, the number of insertions and deletions of each file, and information on rename.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --numstat --stat --oneline` outputs the following:

```
6012d9a9fa69 docs: kvm: Convert timekeeping.txt to ReST format
1       0       Documentation/virt/kvm/index.rst
128     95      Documentation/virt/kvm/{timekeeping.txt => timekeeping.rst}
 Documentation/virt/kvm/index.rst                            |   1 +
 Documentation/virt/kvm/{timekeeping.txt => timekeeping.rst} | 223 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------------------
 2 files changed, 129 insertions(+), 95 deletions(-)
```