# Git: How to get total number of +/- ( Insertions and Deletions) from a single git commit

Tags: git, github

I have a single git commit and would need to get the total number of insertions and deletions.

I know "`git show <SHA>`" is showing about details of my commit but I am  not sure how to get total number of changes only from a particular commit.

`git diff --stat <SHA1> <SHA2>` also does't  work because I should use only a single commit.

Kindly share me if you have any information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should still be able to use [`git diff --stat`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff --stat <SHA>~ <SHA>
# or, for a global total only:
git diff --shortstat <SHA>~ <SHA>
```

The `~` refers to the direct parent of `<SHA>`. You are only using one `<SHA>`: the commit `<SHA>`, and [its direct parent `<SHA>~`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23714994/6309).

For example:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git diff --stat e646ab9cf83025e1000db6ec3c1716f978b099f2~ e646ab9cf83025e1000db6ec3c1716f978b099f2
 po/TEAMS    |    8 +-
 po/ca.po    | 3949 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------------
 po/de.po    | 3776 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------
 po/fr.po    | 3746 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------
 po/git.pot  | 3547 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------
 po/sv.po    | 3723 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------
 po/vi.po    | 3762 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------
 po/zh_CN.po | 4217 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------
 8 files changed, 15007 insertions(+), 11721 deletions(-)
```

For just the total:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git diff --shortstat e646ab9cf83025e1000db6ec3c1716f978b099f2~ e646ab9cf83025e1000db6ec3c1716f978b099f2
 8 files changed, 15007 insertions(+), 11721 deletions(-)
```

Comment: I should use only single commit id and do not have another commit id to use git diff --stat.

Comment: @Girilekkala Exactly: that is what my answer does.

Comment: >fatal: ambiguous argument '<hash>~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. 

I have only one commit.

Comment: @MarkEvans True, 2 commits are needed.

Answer (score 1):

`git show --stat $commitish` is a thing. Not sure how you missed it since you saw the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script which you can enter in terminal:-

```
git config --global alias.total '!echo $(git log --author="$(git
 config user.name)" --no-merges --before=$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT00:00")  --reverse | grep commit | wc -l) commits, $(git log --author="$(
git config user.name)" --no-merges --before=$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT00:00")  --reverse --stat | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,} files? changed" | grep
 -Eo "[0-9]{1,}" | awk "{ sum += \$1 } END { print sum }") files changed, $(git log --author="$(git config user.name)" --no-merges -
-before=$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT00:00")  --reverse --stat | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,} insertions?" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,}" | awk "{ sum += \$1 }
END { print sum }") insertions and $(git log --author="$(git config user.name)" --no-merges --before=$(date "+%Y-%m-01T00:00")  --re
verse --stat | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,} deletions?" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,}" | awk "{ sum += \$1 } END { print sum }") deletions'
```

And use it like this:-

```
git total
```

All credit goes to this nice blog post:-
http://helpfulsheep.com/2016-03-22-what-git-i-do-last-month/