# Is there a way to report git contributions on the command line?

Tags: git, github, command-line

I see that github records the commit, add, and delete history for each contributor. You can check it on the graph tab.

However, it's not as granular as I would like.
Is it possible to get this information on the command line?
I'd like to save a more granular dataset in the form of a table.

What I'm thinking of is four arrays: Day/Date, Commits, Additions, Deletions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with using the [GitHub Statistics API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics) like:

[Get contributors list with additions, deletions, and commit counts](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-contributors-list-with-additions-deletions-and-commit-counts)

It does return:

```
total
```

> The Total number of commits authored by the contributor.

And: Weekly Hash (weeks array):

```
w - Start of the week, given as a Unix timestamp.
a - Number of additions
d - Number of deletions
c - Number of commits
```

For the command-line aspect, use `curl`.
See "[A curl tutorial using GitHub's API](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960) "

---

The above was based on the tag "github", but yes, git itself can generate stats (even fancy ones like the [git-stats project](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats))

See this [gist for instance](https://gist.github.com/lexqt/2720263), or use [`git log --stat`, `git diff --stat`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/199506/3915).
As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13056003/6309), some form of processing is needed, to use the result of a

```
git log --author=$USER --shortstat $BRANCH
```

Comment: I would think git itself would have a way to do this independent of github. No?

Comment: @toshiomagic Yes sorry, I saw the github tag and answered based on that. I have edited the answer to address the native git aspect.